# The MAX(Date) returned incorrect column data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my query below I got the correct return on MAX(Date) but It has incorrect return on BidModifier column. Is there a line that I need to add so that I can get the correct data corresponds to my MAX(Date)?

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT AdGRoupId, Criteria, MAX(DATE) LatestDate , CpcBid, CpcBidSource, 
 BidModifier
 FROM aw_placementbid
 WHERE DATE
 IN (
 SELECT DATE
 FROM aw_placementbid
 GROUP BY AdGroupId, Criteria
 )
 GROUP BY AdGroupId, Criteria
 ORDER BY BidModifier DESC
```

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT AdGRoupId, Criteria, DATE, CpcBid, CpcBidSource, BidModifier
 FROM
 (
   SELECT AdGRoupId, Criteria, DATE, CpcBid, CpcBidSource, BidModifier
   FROM aw_placementbid 
   ORDER BY DATE DESC
 ) AS t
 GROUP BY AdGroupId, Criteria
 ORDER BY BidModifier DESC
```

Firstly, you select all the data you need and order by `DATE`, thus records with a big `DATE` will be ranked in the top.

Then, you divide the temporary table above into several groups(via `GROUP BY AdGroupId, Criteria`).

At last, you just fetch the first row of each group(it must be the row with a `MAX(DATE)` as you have sorted all records before).

Comment: I will try your suggestion and I will double check if I got the correct data. Thank you so much